# How to get the second smallest value in pandas series (pandas.Series.min)?

Tags: python, pandas, series, min

Some of my data contains "0.0" as a placeholder for empty values.

I need to grab the smallest value that's not "0.0".

It would be easy in excel since it will ask you which smallest value you want, but it doesn't look like pandas.Series.min has the option to choose the second smallest.

Keep in mind, I will sometimes have more than one "0" value.

How can I get the smallest value that's not a 0.0?

Comment: `min(s[s != 0.0])` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a series `s`, then you can try:

```
s = pd.Series([1,0.0,2,3])
min(s[s != 0.0])
```

This will return `1.0` in this example. This should give you the second smallest value assuming that all values in your series are greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Hmmm... I will have many zeros. I wonder if somehow importing the series into a set will work

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
s.where(lambda x: x > 0).min()
```

if it can be negative:

```
s.where(lambda x: x != 0).min()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have only positive numbers? If so, here's an alternative solution, sort and take the second value

```
df.sort_values(by='column_name')['column_name'].values[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

So many different ways:
:)

```
min([ x for x in df['Values'] if x != 0.0])
```